# Hotkeys available in Windows 10 "Open With" dialogue

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys, modern-ui

Does it support any hotkeys to navigate and open browse dialog? I cannot seem find to find any information on the internet.

I also tried to set hotkeys using AHK. It also seems hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to have a lot of hotkeys per se, but it is navigable with the keyboard.

When the *How do you want to open this file?* dialog appears, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> to produce the normal *Open with* browser dialog. From there, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> moves up one level. To select an item, you can type its name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move into the main area, in which you can use the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a folder or choose a file.